# Is convex set in an ordered set necessarily interval or ray? Munkres 16. 7

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, alternative-proof

The is Problem 7 in Section 16 (page 92) of Munkres' *Topology*. The problem reads as follows.

> Let $X$ be an ordered set. If $Y$ is a proper subset of $X$ that is
>   convex in $X$, does it follow that $Y$ is an interval or a ray in $X$?

The answer is "No." This problem has been discussed here in MSE at least twice, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493693/is-convex-set-interval-or-ray) and [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432027/if-nonempty-nonsingleton-y-is-a-proper-convex-subset-of-a-simply-ordered-set)

This post is not a duplicate: I think I came up with another counter-example, and I would like to check whether it is correct or not. (I would be proud if it turned out to be right!) Here it goes:

> Let $X=\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ be equipped with the dictionary order. Consider $Y=\{x\times y: -1\leq x\leq 1\}$. Then $Y$ is convex in $X$, but it
>   is not an interval or a ray, as we now prove. If it were an interval,
>   it would be of the form $(a\times b, c\times d), (a\times b, c\times
>  d], [a\times b, c\times d)$ or $[a\times b, c\times d]$ and none of
>   these can be $Y$. Similarly, none of the rays $(a\times b, \infty),
>  [a\times b, \infty),  (\infty, a\times b), (\infty,  a\times b]$ can
>   possibly equal to $Y$.

On the one hand, I think this counter-example works; on the other hand, this means in light of [Brian's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432027/if-nonempty-nonsingleton-y-is-a-proper-convex-subset-of-a-simply-ordered-set#comment923986_432030), $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ is not Dedekind complete (at least under dictionary order), which is I guess strange. Can someone check whether my counter-example is valid or not?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Works, and $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not Dedekind-complete under dictionary order.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks. I trust your judgement; post that as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your counterexample works, and it shows that $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ is not Dedekind-complete under the dictionary order. Indeed the set $Y$ is bounded - above and below - but it has no least upper bound. $(x,y)$ is an upper bound of $Y$ if and only if $x > 1$, and then $(x,y-1)$ is an upper bound too.